# "Can't connect to camera" Error while capturing video Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to capture video in my Android project for that, I have written the following code---

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, selectedMediaUri);
            // start the video capture Intent
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE);
```

plz see the following screen shot-

[image]

Please help me to solve this issue.. Thanks

Comment: please share your logcat

Answer (score 1):

did you add the permission?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Answer (score 1):

In which device you are testing is important as if you are testing on Marshmallow device you will need to grant permission at run time.

Comment: I tested on 3 devices 1] Redmi note 2] Redmi 2 3] ASUS Zen Phone 5

Comment: Is your camera working fine out side the application?

Comment: In favor to store video in storage you will require `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: Yes WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is there in manifest. Also my camera working fine out side the application.

Comment: Given code is working perfect in my demo. There must be device related issue. Try clearing caches of camera.

Comment: I think it is not device issue because my client has reported me the same issue.. He is using Samsung Galaxy

Comment: Happy to help you... please send your solution when you find any solution for the issue.